# Systems of Equations side by side with numbering

Tags: numbering

How can i make this thing in latex;[image]

Comment: The numbers look like subequations (see amsmath page 12).   Note that it stores the old equation number as `\theparentequation` and uses equation as the counter.  While you could  use cases for the left version,  it might be easier to create your own using flalign and  `&(\theequation}&& \left\lbrace\begin{alignat} ... \end{alignat}\right\. &&` etc

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with the first of the examples below: people expect the number to always be on the same side.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for context

\newcommand{\iplus}{\underset{+}{i}}
\newcommand{\ipluss}{\smash[b]{\underset{+}{i}}\vphantom{j}}
\newcommand{\iminus}{\underset{-}{i}}
\newcommand{\iminuss}{\smash[b]{\underset{-}{i}}\vphantom{j}}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{equation}{9}% just to get 10a and 10b

\lipsum[1][1-4]
\begin{subequations}
\[
\hspace{0pt}
\begin{minipage}{0.45\displaywidth}\noindent
\begin{equation}
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
\vphantom{\iplus}
A^{\ipluss}_{\hphantom{\iplus};k} &= A^{i}_{\hphantom{i};k}+A^{s}\Gamma^{i}_{sk} \\
\vphantom{\iplus}
A^{\iminuss}_{\hphantom{\iminus};k} &= A^{i}_{\hphantom{i};k}+A^{s}\Gamma^{i}_{ks}
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}\hspace{1000pt minus 1fill}
\begin{minipage}{0.45\displaywidth}\noindent
\begin{equation}
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
A_{\iplus;k} &= A_{i;k}-A_{s}\Gamma^{i}_{ik} \\
A_{\iminus;k} &= A_{i;k}-A^{s}\Gamma^{i}_{ki}
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}
\]
\end{subequations}
\lipsum[2][1-4]
\begin{subequations}
\[
\refstepcounter{equation}
(\theequation)\quad
\begin{gathered}
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
\vphantom{\iplus}
A^{\ipluss}_{\hphantom{\iplus};k} &= A^{i}_{\hphantom{i};k}+A^{s}\Gamma^{i}_{sk} \\
\vphantom{\iplus}
A^{\iminuss}_{\hphantom{\iminus};k} &= A^{i}_{\hphantom{i};k}+A^{s}\Gamma^{i}_{ks}
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{gathered}
\qquad\qquad
\begin{gathered}
\left.
\begin{aligned}
A_{\iplus;k} &= A_{i;k}-A_{s}\Gamma^{i}_{ik} \\
A_{\iminus;k} &= A_{i;k}-A^{s}\Gamma^{i}_{ki}
\end{aligned}
\right\}
\end{gathered}
\refstepcounter{equation}
\quad(\theequation)
\]
\end{subequations}
\lipsum[3][1-4]

\end{document}
```

Use `\ipluss` and `\iminuss` in order to reduce the height if the symbol is not supposed to have something below it, when in a superscript. I used various other tricks to equalize the braces.

[image]

Comment: Great! Thank you very much.